# Devexpress Gridview Row command Error when Filtering Enabled

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I am using devexpress 9.1.

I have devexpress gridview binded to datasource. have set a page size="20".
Enabled **Settings ShowFilterRow="true"**;

I have column with asp image button setting its command arguments to a value.

Below is the code

```
 <dxwgv:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView2" runat="server" DataSourceID="sds_addingredients" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" KeyFieldName="Ingredients_Id"   ClientInstanceName="grid2">
        <Settings ShowFilterRow="true" />
        <SettingsPager PageSize="20"></SettingsPager>
        <Columns>
        <dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="S.No" VisibleIndex="0" >
        <DataItemTemplate>
        <%#Container.ItemIndex +1 %> 
         </DataItemTemplate>
        </dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>
          <dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn VisibleIndex="1" Caption=" ">
         <DataItemTemplate>
          <asp:ImageButton ID="btn_edit" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Ingredients_Id") %>' Height="15px" 
                        ImageUrl="~/images/document_edit.png"  ToolTip="Edit" 
                        Width="15px" />
                </DataItemTemplate>
            </dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            <dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn VisibleIndex="1" FieldName="Ingredients_Id" 
              ReadOnly="True" Visible="False">
                <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
            </dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            <dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Ingredient" FieldName="Ingredients_Name" VisibleIndex="2"  Settings-ShowFilterRowMenu="True" > 
              </dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>

        </Columns>
```

Below show server side code

```
  protected void ASPxGridView2_RowCommand(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewRowCommandEventArgs e)
    { string id = e.CommandArgs.CommandArgument.ToString();//perform certain opertation based on the id}
```

The above method works properly but when i filter the result and click certain row, **the Id received in the server end** seems to be different not corresponding to what i clicked . i feel it gets the wrong row index...
this happens only when i try filtering and perform row command click.
Other wise it works properly. why is this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using they KeyValue property?

```
 protected void ASPxGridView2_RowCommand(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewRowCommandEventArgs e)
    { 
      int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyValue);
      //perform certain opertation based on the id
    }
```